# Best combined Values 2 columns excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table:

```
DEALS   Frequency  Total profit
1500      12       18000
500       20       10000
30000     5        60000
700       12       8400
```

I want a Formula to find the best frequency with the best total.

Output should be like:

```
  12       18000
```

Comment: Isn't that what the DEALS column show? Sort the table on DEALS and pick the highest value. On all rows the Total profit / Frequency = DEALS.

Comment: actully  i care more about the Frequency thank the Profit so the highest value of Total profit is not that important if the Frequency is low.

Comment: How are you calculating which `Frequency` & which `Profit` is best? What is the criteria that they are the best? Can you kindly explain.

Answer (score 1):

**Frequency:**

```
=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B2:B5-AVERAGE(B2:B5))),ABS(B2:B5-AVERAGE(B2:B5)),0))
```

**Total Profit:**

```
=INDEX(C2:C5,MATCH(MIN(ABS(C2:C5-AVERAGE(C2:C5))),ABS(C2:C5-AVERAGE(C2:C5)),0))
```

Enter the formulas into cell and press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the Help but i am trying to combine both Columns like this way =IFERROR(INDEX($Q$12:$Q$15,SMALL(IF(($Q$12:$Q$15>=LARGE($Q$12:$Q$15,1))+($P$12:$P$15>=LARGE($P$12:$P$15,1)),ROW($Q$12:$Q$15)-ROW($Q$12)+1),ROWS($U$13:U13))),"")